# Purpose of /usr/local/bin/ on Linux system

Tags: script

There are a number of scripts present at this path: `/usr/local/bin/`.

For the user, the instructions are to type the script name `<script_name>` at his prompt `[username@servername]$`. How can that be possible that I didn't type `./script_name` and script started to show results on standard output by just writing the script name on the user prompt?

Comment: I guess, this question will live a happier life over at superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local` is for stuff that you don't want destroyed when you upgrade the operating system.

The OS is free to blow away anything it wants in `/usr/bin` et al, the local variation was set up to prevent this from destroying your non-OS stuff.

And, by placing all this local stuff (`bin`, `etc`, and so on) under one control point, it makes backing up of a site very easy (as opposed to having to get `/bin`, `/etc`, `/lib` and so on for the OS stuff) - you just back up the entire `/usr/local` hierarchy.

If you `echo $PATH`, you'll probably find that `/usr/local/bin` is there. Alternatively, try `which PROG` (replacing `PROG` with your actual program name) to see where it's being found:

```
pax> pwd
/home/pax

pax> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

pax> ls /usr/local/bin/ico*
iconv

pax> which iconv
/usr/local/bin/iconv

pax> iconv -?
Usage: iconv [-c] [-s] [-f fromcode] [-t tocode] [file ...]
or:    iconv -l
Try 'iconv --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

On BSD systems, all non-system software (ports) are installed in `/usr/local` by default.

On most Linux distributions it is intended to be used for software installed by the local administrator from source, bypassing the distributions package manager.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/bin is probably part of your path

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title about the purpose of the /usr/local/bin
 /usr/local are for software local to the machine, usually installed manually (and not via a package management like rpm or deb)

To answer your actual question, I think you should learn about the PATH variable.
try  echo $PATH in a terminal

./somescript.sh means you are expecting the script to be in the current directory (the .)
if you do not put any path, just the name of a command, the shell will look in the PATH to find the command (unless of course it is an internal command of your shell).

Comment: yes, got it, this clears my doubt :-)